# Django use html template from application directory

Tags: python, django

I use django 1.10.3
I want use html template from app dir 
I create app test_page with folder templates and testPage.html

In view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def page(request):
     return render(request, 'test_page/testPage.html', locals())
```

In settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

But it doesn't work. 
How I can use html template from dir application?

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: How I can use html template from dir application?

Answer (score 1):

Directory structure:

```
project/
    test_page/
        templates/
            test_page/
                test_page.html
```

Comment: its doesn't work. Error templates\\<WSGIRequest: GET '\\test\\'>" and   with io.open(origin.name, encoding=self.engine.file_charset) as fp:

Answer (score 0):

When your project name is `django_server` and  app name is `myapp` which is generated using `python manage.py startapp myapp`, the structure should be :

```
django_server/
myapp/
    templates/
         test_page/
              testPage.html
```

Comment: its doesn't work. Error templates\\<WSGIRequest: GET '\\test\\'>" and   with io.open(origin.name, encoding=self.engine.file_charset) as fp:

Comment: im sorry, the formatting was wrong, i updated it now, can u try now